# Killing processes in interruptible sleep state?

Tags: linux, mysql, kill, processes

I'm inserting data from Server A, which is running a Node.js app, into a MySQL database on Server B. I first check for duplicate rows, and then `INSERT` or not depending on the result.
This process can take a while as the table has around 3 million rows, so the queries can be long running.

I've noticed a build up of idle processes on Server A that are being show by `ps xf`:

```
PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND
5521 0   Sl  0:00 mynodeappquery1.js
5522 0   Sl  0:00 mynodeappquery2.js
```

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360252/what-do-the-stat-column-values-in-ps-mean) answer I understand `Sl` standards for interruptible sleep of a child process (I'm forking these queries in Node.js)

Using `mytop` on my database, I can see that these queries have finished executing and are not interacting with the MySQL database.

I assume these are being left running due to a bug in my Node application, however I'd like to know the best ways of killing these processes in the linux environment? Is there a command I can run in a `.sh` script to kill these if inactive for 20 seconds?

Comment: Are there any logs made by these processes that indicate what they've done? Or what does `strace` or `sysdig` show them doing?

Comment: Your question gives me the impression you're looking at this all wrong.  Firstly, a lookup on a 3M record table can take less than a second with the proper hints and indexes.  Secondly, when you get a problem with a script, the solution is not to learn how to stop it but to fix it by troubleshooting it.  Finally, is it possible that your bottleneck is on the network?